# document vs. window objects on android and phonegap - jquery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

i have a simple example that does something when the user changes the orientation of the mobile device:

```
<script>
$(document).on("orientationchange", function(event) {
if (event.orientation === "landscape") {
    // We have changed to landscape orientation, so we have more room
    // Make the headers and footers longer!
    $("header h1").text("jQuery Mobile Demonstration Application")
    $("footer h3").text("O'Reilly Multimedia Services")
} else {
    // Back in portrait orientation, so return header and footer to original length.
    $("header h1").text("jQuery Mobile")
    $("footer h3").text("O'Reilly")
}
})
</script>
```

i downloaded this example (example-3) from https://github.com/jreid01/jqm-api
which is the source code for `O'Reilly Webcast: The jQuery Mobile API In-Depth`  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6Y4a0hA8tI
i loaded this example with PhoneGap:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/example-3.html");
    }
}
```

now, this example doesn't work nigher on my nexus-one nor on an android emulator. after making some experiments, the example did work when i changed `document` to `window`.
what is the reason `document` object doesn't work? what concept am i missing here?

thanks!

Comment: Are you waiting for the deviceready event?

Comment: no.. the only script i have (besides the jquery\mobile scripts) is the one i pasted in the post

Comment: In this case you should read this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple. The "orientation" event does not get fired on the **document** object it is fired on the **window** object. There seems to be a bug in the example you downloaded.